# Usage of a university template produces unrelated errors in xcolor package

Tags: color, document-classes, class-options

I'm new to this forum and I have a question regarding a template.

Here's the basic code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
DIV=13,
12pt,
BCOR=10mm,
twoside,
parskip=half,
automark
]{OTHRartcl}

\title{This is a Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The following errors are produced:

```
Unknown option 'a4paper' for package xcolor.
Unknown option 'DIV' for package xcolor.
Unknown option '12pt' for package xcolor.
Unknown option 'BCOR' for package xcolor.
Unknown option 'twoside' for package xcolor.
Unknown option 'parskip' for package xcolor.
Unknown option 'automark' for package xcolor.
```

I'm opening a document with a custom class (namely OTHRartcl which is based on scrartcl).

If I understand correctly, the specified options regard the base template scrartcl (and partly the OTHRartcl template). But xcolor "thinks" these options are specified for xcolor and throws errors.

Can anybody help me? Is there a way to mute or mitigate these errors?

I may be able to share the template if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you a) add a link to the class and b) add a small test file to your question (as text, not as image)

Comment: do not show black small screenshots. There are people here who can't read that without lots of effort. Copy the error messages.  Beside this: your class seems to pass all its options to xcolor and that won't work with a current xcolor.

Comment: If  this is the template: https://github.com/ditzlike/Vortragstemplate/blob/main/OTHR_colors.sty , then you might want to contact the author to change the option handling: `\RequirePackageWithOptions{xcolor}`...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I updated my question to not include the picture and made it code snippets instead. Thanks for your tip!
Can I change the template myself to not forward all options to xcolor?

Comment: search for the line `\RequirePackageWithOptions{xcolor}` and replace it by `\RequirePackage{xcolor}`. And notify the author of the class.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz This seems to be an older version of the template. The newer (official) version (only available to members of the university via VPN) is no longer maintained as far as I know. At least that is what was told to me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This got rid of the errors. Thank you very much!
I will notify whoever is responsible to change the class.

Comment: Note that restricting access to the class file to members of the university (never mind requiring VPN access) is IMHO extremely bad practice. It is at odds with the collaborative ethos of the TeX community. It takes, while refusing to give. If users are allowed to distribute the class freely, it is pointless obstructionism. If they are not, it means the maintainer had better be prepared to handle all support requests and updates themselves. The policy gains the university nothing but costs.